# waiting for $http.get call to complete

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I know this has something to do with promises but I'm having a hard time understanding how to implement them.

My controller:

```
angular.module('landingApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($http, $q){
    var main = this;

    main.favoritesIds = [];

    $http.get('api/v1/planograms/get_favorites')
      .success(function(data){
        for(var i=0; i < data.planograms.length; i++)
          main.favoritesIds.push(data.planograms[i].id);
      });

    main.isFavorite = function(planogram_id){
      return main.favoriteIds.indexOf(planogram_id) > -1;
    };
```

then in my template I use isFavorite() like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat="planogram in main.planograms">
  <i class="fa fa-star fa-2x favorite" ng-class="{'yellow' : main.isFavorite(planogram.id)}">
```

So basically I want the star icons turned yellow for all planograms marked 'favorite'.  But main.isFavorite() returns undefined I'm guessing because the $http.get method has not resolved.  So my question is how would I implement promises in this situation?

Comment: try then() instead of success()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it doesn't work because you have a typo in `isFavorite` function: it is not `main.favoriteIds`, but `main.favoritesIds`.

Second, it should work regardless of promises. You are right that before the `$http` call is returned, the `main.favoritesIds` is empty, but when it is filled, the array becomes populated, and the `isFavorite` function (being watched by Angular) is re-evaluated.

Although your code would work once the typo is fixed, it is not optimal. Watched functions are called on **every** digest cycle, and should be blazing fast, whereas your `isFavorite` does `isIndexOf`, which has O(n) complexity.

Instead of creating an array of `favoritesIds`, create an object, such that you could do an O(1) lookup. Or, better yet, augment the `planograms` array with favorite data.

For example, with `favoritesIds` as an object:

```
 $http.get('api/v1/planograms/get_favorites')
    .success(function(data){
        for(var i=0; i < data.planograms.length; i++) {
          main.favoritesIds[data.planograms[i].id] = true;
        }
    });

 main.isFavorite = function(planogram_id){
   return main.favoritesIds[planogram_id];
 };
```